# What are the immutable characteristics that uniquely identify a relay?

Tags: relays, directory, protocol

In other words, what are the system "ingredients" that are **not** allowed to change without triggering attribution of a new fingerprint and the restart of the "ramp up" / flagging process?

Please correct any mistakes or oversight below:

- hardware:

  - CPU: **immutable**
  - network controller: **immutable**
  - ..other: mutable?
- IP address: mutable?
- Tor session: **mutable** (process may be restarted, system may be reboot)
- torrc entries (nickname...): mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#UpgradeOrMove). Excerpt (emphasis mine):

> When upgrading your Tor relay, or moving it on a different computer, **the important part is to keep the same identity keys** (stored in "keys/ed25519_master_id_secret_key" and "keys/secret_id_key" **in your DataDirectory**). Keeping backups of the identity keys so you can restore a relay in the future is the recommended way to ensure the reputation of the relay won't be wasted.

**TL;DR:** once the keys are generated, they can be migrated to any machine. Cool!